# how to find the unique smallest topology?

Tags: general-topology

I  have come  across  to  the following question :

Let  $\mathscr{T}_\alpha$  be a family  of  topologies    on  $ X$ .  Show  that   there  is   a  unique  smallest   topology   on  $X$    containing   all   the  collections   $\mathscr{T}_\alpha$ , and  a  unique    largest   topology   contained   in  all  $\mathscr{T}_\alpha$.

I think  that  the unique smallest  topology  equals  the union  of  all  the $\mathscr{T}_\alpha's$, and the unique largest  topology  contained  in  all  $\mathscr{T}_\alpha$  equals  the  intersection of all  the $\mathscr{T}_\alpha's$ .

Comment: The union is not a topology, it generates one.

Comment: If you show just one of: (i) there is a smallest topology containing all the T (ii) there is a largest topology contained in all the T, then the other statement can be seen as a corollary. It's a little easier to verify (ii). Your idea to use the intersection of the family is the correct one.

Comment: @Mike: Why are these corollaries of each other? Wouldn't that only be the case if there were a duality where the complement of a topology is a topology?

Comment: @leopard: A comment I made previously was partly incorrect; I'd misread the question. The correct part of my comment was a hint towards Blah's answer.

Comment: @joriki: Quite generally if you want to show some poset P which has a greatest and largest element is a complete lattice then you need only check that (i) all subsets of P have a lub, or (ii) all subsets of P have a glb. If, say, (i) holds and you have some subset S of P then consider the set S' of all lower bounds for S. The lub of S' is the glb of S.

Comment: That should be "some poset P which has a largest element and a smallest element".

Comment: @dustin, I don't know if this makes any difference, but this post was asked 3 years ago, wheras the one you mentioned was asked a year ago.

Comment: @RobertCardona in the older one they were only asking about the smallest whereas this one is about both. So I think this is a more complete question.

Answer (score 10):

The basic fact to verify is that if $\cal{T}_i$, $i \in I$ is an an indexed collection of topologies on a set $X$, then their intersection $\cap_{i \in I} T = \left\{ A \subset X: \forall i \in I: A \in\cal{T}_i \right\}$ is a topology on $X$ as well. This is straightforward from the topology axioms.

Once this is done, then the smallest topology that contains all $\cal{T}_i$ can be defined as the intersection of all topologies $\cal{T}$ that contain $\cup_{i \in I} T_i$ as a subfamily, and there is at least one (the discrete topology) so we take the intersection of a non-empty family of topologies, which is a topology as we saw above. And it is clearly the smallest one that contains all $\cal{T}_i$: if $\cal{T}$ is any such topology it is one of the topologies we take the intersection of, and thus clearly is a subset of $\cal{T}$.

Also, the largest topology contained in all $\cal{T}_i$ is simply their intersection, and this is clearly the largest topology that is contained in all of them.

Comment: How do you show the uniqueness??

Comment: If there are 2 minimal topologies $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{U}$ that contain all $\mathcal{T}_i$, then $\mathcal{T} \subset \mathcal{U}$, as the former is minimal among all such topologies, and the reverse also holds, reasoning for $\mathcal{U}$, hence equality.

Comment: I don't fully understand, did you take the intersection of $\cup_{i \in I} T_i$ with $\mathcal F$; a family of topologies defined on X s.t each contains $\cup_{i \in I} T_i$ ?

Comment: @jia No, I consider the set of all topologies $\mathcal{T}$ on $X$ such that $\cup_i \mathcal{T}_i \subseteq \mathcal{T}$. This is non-empty, as the discrete topology on $X$ is always in that set. Then I take the intersection of all those topologies, which is a  topology again.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma In the last sentence of your answer, "smallest" should be "largest".

Answer (score 3):

Many texts discuss this question, perhaps leaving some of the verifications to the reader.  For instance you could look [here](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/TopSection4.pdf).

(I guess that by writing these notes and posting them on the web I am implicitly giving the opinion that facts like these are too basic and foundational to make for good exercises for the student.  There is no lack of things to ask a student to solve, so in my opinion as an instructor or a writer you might as well write out the really basic proofs in full.  I note that, for instance, Bourbaki has this philosophy: a lot of "his" exercises are not only more challenging than many dreary propositions proved in full in the body of the text but are more interesting as well.  This is not a very interesting exercise.)

Comment: +1 Because of "This is not a very interesting exercise."  :-D